# MySQL structure for storing user specific settings without 100 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures, normalization

I'm looking for some guidance in the best way to store user specific data in an SQL database. I'm a little new to SQL so I'm hoping this is a fairly easy concept for those familiar.

I've been reading about normalisation and other good practices as I'm aware that setting a good foundation for the database is crucial and hard to change later.

I think an easy way to explain my scenario is this:

- Each website user can choose to create one or more "projects".
- Within each project a user will set an "object". This object can be created by the user or it can be chosen from a list of objects which have been created by other users.
- Each object has a variable number of settings. Let's say an object could have between 5 - 25 settings. Each setting could simply be an integer value between 0 - 100.

Originally I thought about doing it this way:

Project Table

```
+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+------+--------+
| ProjectID | ProjectName | User | Object1 | Object2  | SetID   |  Notes   | Date | Photo  |
+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+------+--------+
| PID0001   | My Project  | Bob  | OBJ0001 | OBJ00056 | SID0045 | my notes |      |        |
+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+------+--------+
```

Each user can create a project and reference different objects and object settings profiles within that project.

Object Table

```
+---------+------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+--------+
|  ObjID  |  ObjName   | ObjVer |  Date   | User  | Set1ID | Set1Name | Set1X | Set1Y | Set1Min | Set1Max | Set2ID |
+---------+------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+--------+
| OBJ0001 | My Object  | Bob    |         | Bob   | S00013 | Volts    |    12 |    52 |       1 |      80 | S00032 |
+---------+------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+--------+
```

This table would define all the configurable settings for the object. It could range from 1 settings to 25 settings. In this example, each setting the user adds to the object would have 6 parameters such as min/max allowed values, name, id etc. 
If I do it this way, I would end up with over 100 columns many of which could be empty...

Object Settings Table

```
+---------+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------+---------+---------+
|  SetID  |   Setname   |  ObjID  |    Date    | User | Set1Val | Set2Val | Set3Val |
+---------+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------+---------+---------+
| SID0045 | My Settings | OBJ0001 | 12-12-2017 | Bob  |      12 |      32 |      98 |
+---------+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

In this table, each row would define a user's settings profile for that object - basically just the value for the settings which were defined in the object table. Each user could have a different set of settings for the same object when it's used in their project.

So, the above method seems bad to me. It makes sense in my head but the number of columns will get out of control when allowing multiple settings.

I suppose the better way of doing this would be to go vertical by adding a row for each setting or setting column but I'm just not sure how this would look. How can I structure it this way while still allowing the "sharing" of objects between user projects?

Comment: In terms of the sharing, you can use a crosswalk that allows the association of many to many or one to many. Create a table ProjectObjects that has (at least) the fields `ObjID` and `ProjectID` so they can be associated. The logic you implement will control the amount of relations that can be set.

Comment: Hi. Don't be "unsure how it looks", work it out. It will involve transformation of these tables--each design's tables are views on the other's. Don't settle for scare quotes around a word, that lets you pretend you've said somthing when you have said nothing. Don't settle for meaningless feely phrases like 'out of control'. You just organized them, they are in control. Is there a problem, and what is it? "A lot" is not a problem, it is a property. Stop thinking about tables & columns and start thinking about what you want the database to express. Object o has value v for setting s, etc.